# Best way to build java desktop app with security

Tags: java, security, spring, user-interface, desktop-application

I'm building some desktop app in Java and i want to know what is the best way to add security into the application (login at startup) and how to tell gui to **disable** some elements. I use Spring and Hibernate. I'm new in Spring framework. Could be Spring Security usable in this scenario if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, Spring Security will enable you to add a User and Roll based authentication mechanism. You will also be able to add methods interceptors/filters to filter results depending on user permissions. (this will help you disable/enable UI elements according to user permissions)

There are a couple of good video presentations to get you started with Spring Security, here - http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/articles.html